# La flor de tiguere

Tags: coloquialismos, palabras-raras, hispanoamérica, inglés, república-dominicana

I was talking to one of my coworker and he told me “ entonces una flor como de tiguere” I did not understand, so I google translated it but I still didn’t get it, and he tried to rephrase it and he said “tú tienes flor de tiguere” but in English it make no sense so can someone explain to me what he mean exactly. I guess that is an expression that Dominican use but I am just wondering the exact slang meaning.

Comment: 'Flor de tigre' tiene sentido, pero no conozco algo como 'flor de tiguere'. ¿En qué contexto te lo dijo? ¿Tenías literalmente una flor o intentó usar una metáfora?

Comment: Here is a link to the English Wikipedia article about the plant called _flor de trigre_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigridia_pavonia Not sure if that helps you.

Comment: It was just a mispronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

**"La flor tíguere" = "La flor tigre"**

En la cuestión hay dos aspectos distintos, "**la flor tíguere**" y el significado de "**tíguere**" en jerga.

- En el primer caso, "**La flor tíguere**", realmente, es como comentaban, referida a "**La flor tigre**", siendo "**tíguere**" una forma **anaptíctica** de la voz "**tigre**". Esta forma apareció en los escritores que pasaron a las Indias Occidentales al haber el vocablo evolucionado en algunas partes de esta nueva zona. Así desde antiguo se puede leer en varios textos "**tíguere**" en lugar de "**tigre**". Por ejemplo entre otros documentos, aparece en Pedro Hernández "*no faltó sino solo uno, que lo mató un **tíguere***", "*matan muchos **tígueres***", o en otro *Suplemento de la Horden de Sant Agustín* se dice "*aquellos rabiosos leopardos y **tígueres***"

La **anaptixis** (Del gr. `epéntesis'), es en fonología una **epéntesis**,  es decir, un tipo de intrusión. *Se denomina de esta forma a la adición de un fonema​ o más en el interior de una palabra, esto es, la intercalación o adición de un segmento, en general vocálico, en una secuencia fonológica. Sucede naturalmente en la evolución de los lenguajes.*

*Diccionario histórico de la lengua española (1960-1996)*

**Anaptixis**

En gramática: "Desarrollo de la resonancia vocálica de las sonánticas hasta convertir esta resonancia en vocal". (Ac. 1970.)

https://www.rae.es/tdhle/anaptixis

*Real Academia Española*

**Anaptixis**

Del gr. ἀνάπτυξις anáptyxis 'epéntesis'.

1. f. Fon. Epéntesis de una vocal entre dos consonantes contiguas, como en corónica por crónica o en calavera, del latín calvaria.

https://dle.rae.es/anaptixis

- Por otra parte "**tíguere**" en jerga se refería a una persona astuta, audaz, seductora, playboy... perezoso, vago, un cualquiera... que intenta sacar provecho o beneficio de todo lo que puede con el mínimo esfuerzo. También aparece en el Diccionario de americanismos con las siguientes acepciones.

*Diccionario de americanismos*

**Tíguere**

I.  1.  m. PR. Tigre.
■
a. ǁ    pelea de ~ y burro. f. PR. Discusión, pelea con ventaja excesiva de uno sobre el otro.

**Tíguere, -a.**

1. sust/adj. RD. Persona golfa, descarada o atrevida, generalmente joven. ◆ tigre.
2. m. y f. RD. Persona cuya identidad se desconoce o no se quiere decir. ◆ tigre.

https://www.asale.org/damer/t%C3%ADguere

**P.D.** Se cree que el primer "**Tíguere**" en el sentido aventurero y playboy del concepto, fue Porfirio Rubirosa Ariza, 1909-1965, el cual se hizo famoso por su estilo de vida.  Se dice que su perfil carismático, seductor y aventurero pudo haber servido de inspiración para el personaje del agente secreto 007.